# Unwanted horizontal scroll

Tags: html, css, scroll

I have a very simple problem, but I can't solve it.

There is a div inside another div. The inner div is positioned absolutely out of the outer div (left: 100%). Moreover, the outer div should scroll vertically. However, I can't find how not to scroll horizontally and how to make the inner div be visible outside the outer div, at the same time.

The code is the following:

HTML:

```
<div id="out">
   <div id="in">
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#out{
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  background-color: green;
  position: relative;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: visible;
}

#in{
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  height:50px;
  width:50px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.main_outer{
  overflow-y:scroll;
  border:thin black solid;
overflow-x:hidden;
}

#out{
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  background-color: green;
  position: relative;
}

#in{
  position: absolute;
  left:100%;
  width:70px;
  height:auto;
  background-color: red;
  right:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="main_outer">
<div id="out">
<div id="in">
   Your Inner Contents
   Your Inner Contents
   Your Inner Contents
 
   </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Here is [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0bvme4dn/4/)

**PS:** Change your red div size to fit your contents.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you for your answer! However, the red div should be on the right side of the green div. In other words, the red div should be displayed outside the green div.

Comment: in your question , you mentioned there is a div inside another div. that's why i have put this solution. can you be more specific what output you are expecting?

Comment: I say that because that the hierarchy in the html. Sorry for the misunderstanding. The output should be like this: https://postimg.org/image/n2fl7ceen/

Comment: I have updated my answer. is this the same that you wanted?

Answer (score 1):

Fixed the scroll with removing the `overflow-x:hidden;`

================ Latest Change ======================

See the latest change if this is what required but a little tweak in markup.

```css
#outer-div {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  width: 165px;    
}
#out{
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  background-color: green;
  position: relative;
}

#in{
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  height:50px;
  width:50px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer-div">
  <div id="out">
   <div id="in">
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: as you see in the discription, the outer div must scroll vetrtically.

Comment: Now fixed the horizontal scroll bar.

Comment: I see but the red div is not visible

Comment: How you suppose to see that you have set the ```width:100px```. Btw let me fix that.

Comment: that is very close to what the output should be. Is there any way to keep only the vertical scrollbar?

Comment: @themis93 If the content will increase or decrease the outer-div height the scroll button will appear.